# Kaa endpoint identification

Tags: kaa

Right now Im stuck with a problem. How to distinguish data received from various endpoints? I know each end point has an endpoint hash logged into the header part of the record. 
But, how do I expose this to an external API which needs to query data received from a specific endpoint? Do I have to generate a unique identifier at the endpoint and use it in the log along with other fields, or 
Does Kaa provide any endpoint identification that be exposed out of Kaa?

Any help is greately appreciated.